# Failed: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined] , Unit Test using Angular, Jasmine, Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Hi to all experienced developer here. Currently I'm working on Unit Test using Angular, Jasmine, Karma, implemented on mobile apps that using Ionic Framework. But then, I encountered below error.

> ProfilePage >
> it should set isOpenTermsOfUse to false Failed: Uncaught
> (in promise): [object Undefined]

The unit test code is as below:

```
  it('it should set isOpenTermsOfUse to false', () => {
        component.isOpenTermsOfUse = true;
        component.closeTermsOfUse();
        expect(component.isOpenTermsOfUse).toEqual(false);   
  });
```

In addition, I can successfully run the code, if I target unit test to specific file path only, like codes below that targeted to profile.page.spec.ts.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: {
  context(path: string, deep?: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
    <T>(id: string): T;
    keys(): string[];
  };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\/profile\.page\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

If I run 'ng test' where it will run all the .spec.ts file, it will produce the topic of this issue. The code is as below.

```
// This file is required by karma.conf.js and loads recursively all the .spec and framework files

import 'zone.js/dist/zone-testing';
import { getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

declare const require: {
  context(path: string, deep?: boolean, filter?: RegExp): {
    <T>(id: string): T;
    keys(): string[];
  };
};

// First, initialize the Angular testing environment.
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting()
);
// Then we find all the tests.
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// And load the modules.
context.keys().map(context);
```

Below is my angular version:

Angular CLI: 14.2.4
Node: 16.17.1
Package Manager: npm 8.15.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.2.4

```
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.4
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.4
@angular/google-maps            14.2.3
@schematics/angular             14.2.4
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.8.4
```

My Ionic Version:
6.20.3

What I have tried:

1. npm i --legacy-peer-deps
2. Resolve any missing imports and provider on .spec.ts file

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue by mocking the keycloak instance on each .spec.ts file.